# Passing a value in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying the tutorial from infotuts here:
http://www.infotuts.com/ajax-table-add-edit-delete-rows-dynamically-jquery-php/

And there's a javascript like this:

```
 $(function(){
 $.ajax({
         url:"DbManipulate.php",
                  type:"POST",
                  data:"actionfunction=showData",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){

          $('#demoajax').html(response);
          createInput();

        }

       });
```

Now I want to add a parameter so that the line:
url:"DbManipulate.php" becomes url:"DbManipulate.php?q=[some value]

I tried to alter the script like this:

```
 var cat=2;

 $(function(){
 $.ajax({
         url:"DbManipulate.php?q="+cat.val(),
                  type:"POST",
                  data:"actionfunction=showData",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){

          $('#demoajax').html(response);
          createInput();

        }

       });
```

But it doesn't work. The variable cat never gets into the function. How to pass the variable "cat" so that the DbManipulate.php file receives the $q variable and I can use it using $_GET?

Thank you

Comment: you are using POST, when you tack a variable to the end of the url that is a GET function.  In my experience that doesnt work.  You should add variable cat to your data that you send (POST)

Comment: there could be more errors, but try changing your data: to `data:"actionfunction=showData&q="+cat.val()",`

Comment: In your altered script, `var cat=2;` is an integer, so you don't need to use `.val()` to get the value. It should be just `url:"DbManipulate.php?q="+cat,`. But that will only work if you send it with type GET as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply this way to sent your data variable(cat) using `GET` Method

```
var cat=2;
$(function(){
 $.ajax({
         url:"DbManipulate.php",
         type:"GET",
         data:{actionfunction:showData,cat:cat},
         cache: false,
         success: function(response){
          console.log(response);
          $('#demoajax').html(response);
          createInput();
        }
       });

 // in DbManipulate.php, try to catch cat using $_GET like this
  $cat=$_GET['cat'];
 //do further processing
```

**EDIT**

```
cat=2;
url="DbManipulate.php";
function yourFunc(cat,url){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url+'?q='+cat,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        $('#demoajax').html(response);
              createInput();
    }
});
}
//in DbManipulate.php 
 $cat=$_GET['q'];
```

More Info:http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/